oidc client ts skipping login process
I have 2 applications App A and App B. I have my App b wrapped with oidc client ts library in react. I want to start a session without login process. If I have a token from App A which is validated and both apps use same domain authority. I want to start a session in App B without login because user already authenticated in App A, if I redirect from App A to App B. my App is wrapped with React Oidc context library. Assuming I already have valid token for App b
I tried silent signin its not possible we still didnt start session in APP B. I tried prompt = none, it throws error

For that to work you need to share the underlying token storage. For example you could use oidc-client-ts in both apps and share state like this:
userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: localStorage })

DEPLOYMENT
For the above to work, both apps must be deployed to the same domain. It would not work for the below deployment:

https://www.product1.com
https://www.product2.com

Be aware of this, eg token sharing might work if using localhost URLs on a development computer but may not work in deployed environments.
LEAST PRIVILEGE TOKENS
If your two apps are for different business areas, then each app should get its own tokens with restricted privileges. You can still use Single Sign On to navigate across the apps in a user-friendly way.
Sharing tokens is alright in a micro-frontend deployment though, where multiple apps are produced for the same business area, solely to keep code size manageable.
SECURE TOKENS
It is not considered a good security practice to store tokens in local storage since malicious JavaScript is a concern for browser based apps and might exfiltrate and misuse the tokens.
A more secure option is to encrypt tokens into HTTP-only cookies (using a Backend for Frontend) and share those across micro-frontends instead.
SUMMARY
There are potential pitfalls to sharing tokens between apps, so be aware of them. It is usually safer to use SSO instead.
